# How to connect to Redshift serverless (using CLI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

Given a Redshift serverless cluster and a `dummy_table`,

when trying to connect to it in the AWS Cloudshell using `aws redshift-data execute-statement --endpoint-url https://default.XXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com --database dev --sql 'SELECT * FROM dummy_table' --secret-arn redshift-serverless-default-secret --workgroup-name default`

then I get a `Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://default.XXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com/"`.

The same SQL statement works well using the Redshift query editor v2. Could anypoint give me some pointers how to analyze this problem further / what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded after these steps:

- ensure that workgroup is publicly accessible (I clicked the button multiple times beforehand and didn't realize it had no effect! The subnets have to be configured correctly)
- afterwards run a simpler command: `aws redshift-data execute-statement --workgroup-name default --database dev --sql "SELECT * FROM DummyTable"`